# Leaflet GeoJSON with Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete, leaflet, geojson

I have a problem. How do a autocomplete when I search for something?

I have this:

```
<form>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <input type="text" name="busca" id="txtSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar..." />
    </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnSearch"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Nothing more, just a form with a input text and a buttom. When write anything I need that autocomplete, when find the word click in buttom.

And my Js have:

```
stComerciaisLayer = L.geoJSON(setoresComerciais, {
                style: function (feature) {
                    ...
                },
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);
```

The variable stComercialLayer is a object that generate the mapping layers. setoresComerciais is the same variable in my json (geoSetoresComerciais)

```
    setoresComerciais={
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "totalFeatures": 116,
      "features": [
        {
         (...)
```

and

```
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                source: setoresComerciais
            });
```

is the autocomplete, but the source, I need a function or a array for work, I think.

The problem is that stComerciaisLayer is a Object and the source just accept type Array, String or Function, conform jquery UI's documentation :(
What i need do?

Resuming: I just need that the autocomplete works! My code is on the git:

https://github.com/eltonsantos/leaflet-tests/tree/master/teste2

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, you should pass an array to source below:

```
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                source: setoresComerciais
            });
```

And as you note, setoresComerciais is a geojson object. But, this geojson contains an array of features within in, and we can use this to get the autocorrect working.

Because your geojson is a feature collection: `type:"FeatureCollection"`, all your features are located in setoresComerciais.features (an array). Each feature is also an object, but if we iterate through each feature in this array with array.map() we can get an array that contains one string per feature that you can use for the autocomplete function:

```
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
    source: setoresComerciais.features.map(function(d) { return d.properties.sco_dsc_sa; })
});
```

.map allows use to iterate through the features array, the function takes one argument (an item in the array) and allows us to return a value into a new array (as an array is returned by .map()).

I chose a property at random (there are duplicates, you could remove those relatively easily, but I imagine that you will choose a property that is unique to each marker).

Comment: Excelent!! Thanks! And for zoom on find locate? I tried select: function(event, ui){ map.fitBounds(setoresComerciais[ui.item.value].getBounds()); } But dont work. And I added in source's return this: return d.properties.sco_num_sc + " - " + d.properties.sco_dsc_sa. When find what looking for, need have a zoom in locate found. I need learn Javascript :( I have many difficulties to learn Functions. :/

Comment: I will take a look, but you should probably post this as a new question - otherwise it'll just be me seeing it. Plus there is more room to expand the question and more room to answer (and better formatting options).

Comment: Ok, I will open a new question. I try to avoid asking questions, because I've already been banned from here for 6 months due to poor questioning and so I do not want to be banned again......

Comment: I understand your concerns, but it would be best. I can edit it if language is a concern (I just updated this question, I hope it looks ok to you)

Comment: Ok, I asked the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419475/zoom-after-search-using-autocomplete

Comment: Looks good, I'm a bit busy at the moment, but if no one answers by this afternoon I should be able to get you an answer.